# Bizarre for-next loop skip step behavior in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, iteration

The following code is exhibiting the following bizarre behavior:
1.) if I set the step to zero it moves from cell to cell just fine, the message box counts out 1 through 8 (For i = 1 to 8 Step 0).
2.) if I set the step to one it gives the sequence 1, 3, 5, 7 (For i = 1 to 8 Step 1). It is my understanding that Step 1 should be producing 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 for the message box return.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 8 Step 1
MsgBox i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    i = i + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

The math of this makes sense of course, but the mechanics according to standard excel looping seems bizarre because this yields the same result as (with no step increment specified):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 8 
MsgBox i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    i = i + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

that is the MsgBox sequence is 1, 3, 5, 7.  The point is that I know appending "Step 0" to the for statement gives the unitary increments but this feels like a work-around for leaving off the Step increment all together?  I have to wonder if my 2013 excel pro plus is corrupted.  Please clue me in as to whether this is normal or not.  TIA.

Comment: Typically you should not be changing the value of a loop counter within the loop.  You don't need the `i=i+1` here: that's not how loops work - `Next i` takes care if the increment.

Comment: wow, I am embarrassed, this was a very amateur move on my part, considering how nasty most of my code usually winds up being and I space out on this.  I really appreciate your assistance.  Maybe I have been drinking way too much coffee lately.  Thank you kindly.  The post however may stand if the powers that bee see fit.  Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you have this line in the code:

```
i = i + 1
```

Which makes it jump double because it's your loop variable too!

So For increments the variable for you, you don't have to do i = i + 1 in the loop. You would have to, if it was a while loop. But never in a For loop, because you're interfering with the loop. (Unless this is your exact intention.)

Answer (score -1):

Folks what can I say? Well a little more actually,  if you look at the block of code that I didn't include:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 8 Step 0
MsgBox i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
 i = i + 1  

Next i
End Sub
```

you might be able to appreciate the value of  the "Step 0", this allows the user total control over the incremental step via i = i +1, or more generally for a function f(), i = f(i).  Hence not incrementing at the "For i = ..." level may actually have some utility depending on what kind of jam one find's oneself in.

In summary: a.) leaving out the Step modifier is equivalent to the default i.e., Step = 1.  b.) zeroing the Step modifier, Step = 0 requires a "do while" approach with explicit incrementing via i = f(i) placed within the loop.  Finally, and I'm not going to test this, but with Step = 0 and no increasing incrementing may cause an infinite loop or throw an error depending on the situation (so it is probably a good idea to avoid Step = 0 unless you are sure about your f(i) and it's placement within the loop block!).

Comment: You are making too much of a basic mistake.  the answer is not increment inside a For loop unless you have an actual reason.  Uou haven't shown one.

Comment: Agreed, i = f(i) = i + 1 is built into a for-next loop structure, so as Lazlo stated the loop count is short circuited from achieving its pre-assigned role.  The step = 0 however is an option but as you have stated very much unjustified in my given situation (think blown < amateur < rookie < pro :) )